# run time error in android activity has been stopped

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

I just built a demo application through [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) and when I run the application I get the following error in log cat and the main application is stopped. Does anyone know why I am getting this error?

```
05-11 15:52:06.492: E/AndroidRuntime(584): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-11 15:52:06.492: E/AndroidRuntime(584): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidhive.jsonparsing/com.androidhive.jsonparsing.AndroidJSONParsingActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-11 15:52:06.492: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
05-11 15:52:06.492: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-11 15:52:06.492: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-11 15:52:06.492: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-11 15:52:06.492: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-11 15:52:06.492: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-11 15:52:06.492: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-11 15:52:06.492: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-11 15:52:06.492: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-11 15:52:06.492: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-11 15:52:06.492: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-11 15:52:06.492: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-11 15:52:06.492: E/AndroidRuntime(584): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-11 15:52:06.492: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
05-11 15:52:06.492: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
05-11 15:52:06.492: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
05-11 15:52:06.492: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
05-11 15:52:06.492: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
05-11 15:52:06.492: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
05-11 15:52:06.492: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
05-11 15:52:06.492: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
05-11 15:52:06.492: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
05-11 15:52:06.492: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
05-11 15:52:06.492: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
05-11 15:52:06.492: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at com.androidhive.jsonparsing.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:38)
05-11 15:52:06.492: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at com.androidhive.jsonparsing.AndroidJSONParsingActivity.onCreate(AndroidJSONParsingActivity.java:54)
05-11 15:52:06.492: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-11 15:52:06.492: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-11 15:52:06.492: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
05-11 15:52:06.492: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverlow. Please before posting questions do a search to see if your question has been asked before. Your question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612406/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-need-to-use-async-task,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413625/android-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208494/error-in-http-connection-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception,

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild the same for android target before 3.0 (such as for 2.1). Androids before 3.0 don't check if you're making network connections on main thread. 
After it works as a quick fix then move your networking away from the main thread.

see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html